# Banana connector confusion [Male and Female?]

Tags: banana-jack

I recently bought few pairs(male and female(that's what I asked for)) of banana connectors for my home project. I didn't check what the storekeeper gave me because I never had any complains with what he handed me. And I guess that's the mistake I did probably.

Here's a picture of what I got.
[image]

Every pair had black and white ones.

I tried inserting the metal of one into the hole of another but the connection is pretty loose.[image]

Does this kind of pair exist as a banana connector pair or is it the case of wrong delivery from the store-keeper?

And finally, is there any way to work with these connectors. I can't get outside due to the shutdown in my area.

Comment: That first photo looks like a pair of banana plugs (i.e. male). A female would have much wider metal body.

Comment: Yeah, both of them are same in size.

Comment: Guess he misunderstood your use of "pair" to mean red and black. Female banana plugs are much more common in the form of sockets mounted to panels.

Comment: That's probably what he thought. But I can tell you that he is probably the most experienced seller in my area. So I had to think he may not have made a mistake.

Comment: I would have made the same assumption if you asked for a "pair of banana connectors".    I would have given you red & black male plugs too.  I don't think I've ever even seen a female banana jack "inline" (i.e. made to be put on the end of a piece of wire).  As mentioned above, they're nearly always panel-mounted.   Not saying such doesn't exist, but uncommon enough that I've never run across one in 30 years of being an EE.

Comment: Don't think I've ever seen one but [they do exist](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/banana-plugs-connectors/1902767/)

Comment: Any suggestions on how I should work with these? I

Comment: You have two perfectly good plugs. Just buy two matching sockets and you're good. If you can only find panel-mounting ones, also buy some heat-shrink insulating sleeving that will fit over the screw threaded part to avoid shorting exposed connections.